# Find a positive integer solution to $xyzw=504(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations, vieta-jumping

> Find positive integer values of $x,y,z,w$, such that $$xyzw=504(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)$$

I found it at some point and now I am unable to find the solution anymore, maybe this equation isn't satisfiable? But how do one prove such thing?

**Edit** @Dashisan found nice example $(x,y,z,w)=(21,63,84,84)$. Now, the problem is if there  exists distinct positive integer solution.

Comment: Why 504?????????????

Comment: Did you do anything else? Find the factors of $504$, for example? If you arbitrarily set $x\ge y\ge z\ge w$, how much bigger can $x$ be than everything else?

Comment: because Now I have creat a problem with  reslut  $504\times 4=2016$

Comment: taking $(63, 42, 42, 42)$ or $(84, 42, 42, 42)$ works but I don't see any way to figure that out without bruteforce. It might help to note that $504 = 42 \cdot 12$.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams,have some $x,y,z,w$ different solutions?

Comment: @WillJagy: It turns out we can contrive a Pell-like equation $ap^2-bq^2 = 504 \times 4 =2016$ per OP's comments. Kindly see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a *Pell-like equation*, there are in fact infinitely many positive integer solutions to,

$$xyzw=504(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)\tag1$$

> **$1$st family:**

$$\big(x,y,z,w\big)=\big(84,\;84,\;21q,\;21(4p+7q)\big)$$

where, $$p^2-3q^2=-2\tag2$$

An initial point is $(p,q) = (-1,1)$ yielding the OP's known $\big(x,y,z,w\big)=\big(84,\;84,\;21,\;63\big)$. As $(2)$ has infinitely many positive integer solutions, then so does $(1)$.

> **$2$nd family:**

$$\big(x,y,z,w\big)=\big(36,\;36,\;9(4p+5q),\;9(8p+11q)\big)$$

where, $$p^2-2q^2=14\tag3$$

An initial point is $(p,q) = (4,-1)$ yielding $\big(x,y,z,w\big)=\big(36,\;36,\;99,\;189\big)$. And infinitely more.

(***Added a day later.***)

> **More generally:**

$$\big(x,y,z,w\big)=\big(12c,\;12c,\;c(ap+7bq-ac^2q),\;c(bp-7aq+bc^2q)\big)$$

with the *Pell-like*,

$$\beta\, p^2-\beta(c^4-49)\,q^2=7\times 288=\color{blue}{2016}$$

where $\beta=-7 a^2 - 7 b^2 + 2 a b c^2$ for arbitrary $a,b,c$ and we recover the $2016$ [asked by the OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861816/find-a-positive-integer-solution-to-xyzw-504x2y2z2w2#comment3813018_1861816). The first two families were just special cases.

Comment: What about $(24,63,66,69)$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: That may belong to another one. The two families I gave settle whether there are infinitely many integer solutions. However, there might also be infinitely many families as well using different Pell-like equations.

Comment: @Tito Piezas: I feel you can get infinitely many infinite families with analogue procedure making $x=y$. I have deleted my answer but I undelete it for you in case you were interested (after two days I shall delete it again). I felt before there are an infinity of solutions and you have to prove this.

Comment: @Piquito: I edited my answer. It turned out there are indeed infinitely many families.

Comment: Tito, if I have not mentioned this before, see http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf  which is pretty easy German. The hopping motion involved in traveling a Hurwitz tree is the same as that in the Markov Numbers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number  The constant 504 throws that off quite a bit.

Comment: Oh, on sequences of solutions giving constant values for a quadratic form (binary indefinite), the branch of slowest growth in the Markov tree is every other Fibonacci number. other such sequences happen by starting at other nodes and continuing in the direction of slowest growth.

Comment: @WillJagy: Sorry, I can't read even easy German. :/ But thanks for the reference

Comment: I put an answer with the easiest case of the Hurwitz/Markov type of idea.

Comment: @WillJagy: Ah, nice.

Answer (score 2):

$(x, y, z, w) = (21, 63, 84, 84)$ works.

Comment: Nice! +1 ,How do  find this example?can you explain

Comment: I used a computer program as it wasn't very hard to code. There were many solutions it found btw, but this was the first one.

Comment: can you give other, I hope can $x,y,z,w$ different Thanks

Comment: Well there are a lot... you can easily write a program to check for you. Just brute-force search.

Answer (score 1):

Tell you what. It happens that
$$ 2xyzw = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 $$
is not possible in positive integers. The way to approach this successfully is what they call [Vieta Jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping).

See what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

The following Haskell script searches exhaustively for integer solutions in $[0,100]^4$:

```
xs = [0..100]
ys = [0..100]
zs = [0..100]
ws = [0..100]


p :: (Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer) -> Bool
p (x,y,z,w) = (x*y*z*w==504*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2))


sols :: [(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)]
sols = filter p [ (x,y,z,w) | x <- xs, y <- ys, z <- zs, w <- ws ]
```

Running the script, we obtain lots of integer solutions:

```
λ sols
[(0,0,0,0),(21,63,84,84),(21,72,75,75),(21,75,72,75),(21,75,75,72),(21,84,63,84),(21,84,84,63),(24,63,66,69),(24,63,69,66),(24,66,63,69),(24,66,69,63),(24,69,63,66),(24,69,66,63),(26,54,62,91),(26,54,91,62),(26,62,54,91),(26,62,91,54),(26,91,54,62),(26,91,62,54),(28,42,84,98),(28,42,98,84),(28,84,42,98),(28,84,98,42),(28,98,42,84),(28,98,84,42),(29,51,56,69),(29,51,69,56),(29,54,56,61),(29,54,61,56),(29,56,51,69),(29,56,54,61),(29,56,61,54),(29,56,69,51),(29,61,54,56),(29,61,56,54),(29,69,51,56),(29,69,56,51),(30,42,69,90),(30,42,90,69),(30,69,42,90),(30,69,90,42),(30,90,42,69),(30,90,69,42),(31,39,76,84),(31,39,84,76),(31,76,39,84),(31,76,84,39),(31,84,39,76),(31,84,76,39),(33,42,57,72),(33,42,72,57),(33,57,42,72),(33,57,72,42),(33,72,42,57),(33,72,57,42),(34,42,57,62),(34,42,62,57),(34,57,42,62),(34,57,62,42),(34,62,42,57),(34,62,57,42),(36,36,63,81),(36,36,81,63),(36,63,36,81),(36,63,81,36),(36,81,36,63),(36,81,63,36),(37,41,54,56),(37,41,56,54),(37,54,41,56),(37,54,56,41),(37,56,41,54),(37,56,54,41),(39,31,76,84),(39,31,84,76),(39,76,31,84),(39,76,84,31),(39,84,31,76),(39,84,76,31),(41,37,54,56),(41,37,56,54),(41,54,37,56),(41,54,56,37),(41,56,37,54),(41,56,54,37),(42,28,84,98),(42,28,98,84),(42,30,69,90),(42,30,90,69),(42,33,57,72),(42,33,72,57),(42,34,57,62),(42,34,62,57),(42,42,42,63),(42,42,42,84),(42,42,63,42),(42,42,84,42),(42,57,33,72),(42,57,34,62),(42,57,62,34),(42,57,72,33),(42,62,34,57),(42,62,57,34),(42,63,42,42),(42,69,30,90),(42,69,90,30),(42,72,33,57),(42,72,57,33),(42,84,28,98),(42,84,42,42),(42,84,98,28),(42,90,30,69),(42,90,69,30),(42,98,28,84),(42,98,84,28),(51,29,56,69),(51,29,69,56),(51,56,29,69),(51,56,69,29),(51,69,29,56),(51,69,56,29),(54,26,62,91),(54,26,91,62),(54,29,56,61),(54,29,61,56),(54,37,41,56),(54,37,56,41),(54,41,37,56),(54,41,56,37),(54,56,29,61),(54,56,37,41),(54,56,41,37),(54,56,61,29),(54,61,29,56),(54,61,56,29),(54,62,26,91),(54,62,91,26),(54,91,26,62),(54,91,62,26),(56,29,51,69),(56,29,54,61),(56,29,61,54),(56,29,69,51),(56,37,41,54),(56,37,54,41),(56,41,37,54),(56,41,54,37),(56,51,29,69),(56,51,69,29),(56,54,29,61),(56,54,37,41),(56,54,41,37),(56,54,61,29),(56,61,29,54),(56,61,54,29),(56,69,29,51),(56,69,51,29),(57,33,42,72),(57,33,72,42),(57,34,42,62),(57,34,62,42),(57,42,33,72),(57,42,34,62),(57,42,62,34),(57,42,72,33),(57,62,34,42),(57,62,42,34),(57,72,33,42),(57,72,42,33),(61,29,54,56),(61,29,56,54),(61,54,29,56),(61,54,56,29),(61,56,29,54),(61,56,54,29),(62,26,54,91),(62,26,91,54),(62,34,42,57),(62,34,57,42),(62,42,34,57),(62,42,57,34),(62,54,26,91),(62,54,91,26),(62,57,34,42),(62,57,42,34),(62,91,26,54),(62,91,54,26),(63,21,84,84),(63,24,66,69),(63,24,69,66),(63,36,36,81),(63,36,81,36),(63,42,42,42),(63,66,24,69),(63,66,69,24),(63,69,24,66),(63,69,66,24),(63,81,36,36),(63,84,21,84),(63,84,84,21),(66,24,63,69),(66,24,69,63),(66,63,24,69),(66,63,69,24),(66,69,24,63),(66,69,63,24),(69,24,63,66),(69,24,66,63),(69,29,51,56),(69,29,56,51),(69,30,42,90),(69,30,90,42),(69,42,30,90),(69,42,90,30),(69,51,29,56),(69,51,56,29),(69,56,29,51),(69,56,51,29),(69,63,24,66),(69,63,66,24),(69,66,24,63),(69,66,63,24),(69,90,30,42),(69,90,42,30),(72,21,75,75),(72,33,42,57),(72,33,57,42),(72,42,33,57),(72,42,57,33),(72,57,33,42),(72,57,42,33),(72,75,21,75),(72,75,75,21),(75,21,72,75),(75,21,75,72),(75,72,21,75),(75,72,75,21),(75,75,21,72),(75,75,72,21),(76,31,39,84),(76,31,84,39),(76,39,31,84),(76,39,84,31),(76,84,31,39),(76,84,39,31),(81,36,36,63),(81,36,63,36),(81,63,36,36),(84,21,63,84),(84,21,84,63),(84,28,42,98),(84,28,98,42),(84,31,39,76),(84,31,76,39),(84,39,31,76),(84,39,76,31),(84,42,28,98),(84,42,42,42),(84,42,98,28),(84,63,21,84),(84,63,84,21),(84,76,31,39),(84,76,39,31),(84,84,21,63),(84,84,63,21),(84,98,28,42),(84,98,42,28),(90,30,42,69),(90,30,69,42),(90,42,30,69),(90,42,69,30),(90,69,30,42),(90,69,42,30),(91,26,54,62),(91,26,62,54),(91,54,26,62),(91,54,62,26),(91,62,26,54),(91,62,54,26),(98,28,42,84),(98,28,84,42),(98,42,28,84),(98,42,84,28),(98,84,28,42),(98,84,42,28)]
```

One positive integer solution with **distinct** components is $(24,63,66,69)$.

Comment: By symmetry, each permutation of the solution $(x,y,z,w)=(a,b,c,d)$ gives another solution but it is trivially "the same" that $(a,b,c,d)$. Therefore, your list of solutions could be shorter. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito Sure, but filtering out permutations is more work than I am willing to do for free.

Comment: I understand and agree good grace but not in my case the answer I could give. It happens that I work a lot for free. Thank you for your list. Best regards.

Comment: @Piquito One could create the $4$-tuples such that $x < y < z < w$ always holds, to avoid generating permutations. I, too, do a lot of work for free, but perhaps my hobby is making it hard for others to earn a living teaching math. Too many enthusiasts online.

Comment: @Piquito I won't even remember this conversation 15 minutes from now!

Answer (score 1):

The solution with the smallest maximum is $56;$

```
56  54   41  37
61  56   54  29
62  57   42  34
63  42   42  42
69  56   51  29
69  66   63  24
72  57   42  33
75  75   72  21
81  63   36  36
84  42   42  42
84  76   39  31
84  84   63  21
90  69   42  30
91  62   54  26
98  84   42  28
```

Next, if we fix two of the numbers, call them $W = 56, Z = 54,$ we get an indefinite binary quadratic form in $x,y$ that has infinitely many solutions. It works best when $WZ$ is a multiple of $504,$ because then we get a Vieta Jumping situation:
$$ 56 \cdot 54 = 3024 = 504 \cdot 6. $$
From $wzxy = 504(w^2 + z^2 + x^2 + y^2)$ we have
$$ 6 \cdot 504 \cdot xy = 504 (56^2 + 54^2 + x^2 + y^2), $$
$$ 6xy = 56^2 + 54^2 + x^2 + y^2,  $$
$$ x^2 - 6 xy + y^2 = -6052.  $$
We see that solutions require $x,y>0,$ and we already have $41, 37.$
It is a exercise in Vieta Jumping to display all the solutions for $ x^2 - 6 xy + y^2 = -6052.  $ They come in two doubly infinite Vieta orbits,
$$  (6113,1049); \; (1049, 181); \; (181,37); \; (37,41); \; (41,209); \; (209,1213),  $$
$$  (3781,649); \; (649, 113); \; (113,29); \; (29,61); \; (61,337); \; (337,1961),  $$

I told the machine to sort by $x+y$

```
x+y
78   x:  37  y:  41
78   x:  41  y:  37
90   x:  29  y:  61
90   x:  61  y:  29
142   x:  113  y:  29
142   x:  29  y:  113
218   x:  181  y:  37
218   x:  37  y:  181
250   x:  209  y:  41
250   x:  41  y:  209
398   x:  337  y:  61
398   x:  61  y:  337
762   x:  113  y:  649
762   x:  649  y:  113
1230   x:  1049  y:  181
1230   x:  181  y:  1049
1422   x:  1213  y:  209
1422   x:  209  y:  1213
2298   x:  1961  y:  337
2298   x:  337  y:  1961
4430   x:  3781  y:  649
4430   x:  649  y:  3781
7162   x:  1049  y:  6113
7162   x:  6113  y:  1049
8282   x:  1213  y:  7069
8282   x:  7069  y:  1213
13390   x:  11429  y:  1961
13390   x:  1961  y:  11429
25818   x:  22037  y:  3781
25818   x:  3781  y:  22037
41742   x:  35629  y:  6113
41742   x:  6113  y:  35629
48270   x:  41201  y:  7069
48270   x:  7069  y:  41201
78042   x:  11429  y:  66613
78042   x:  66613  y:  11429
150478   x:  128441  y:  22037
150478   x:  22037  y:  128441
243290   x:  207661  y:  35629
243290   x:  35629  y:  207661
281338   x:  240137  y:  41201
281338   x:  41201  y:  240137
454862   x:  388249  y:  66613
454862   x:  66613  y:  388249
x + y
```

---

What happens when $WZ$ is not a multiple of $504?$ It is similar, but not directly what you know as Vieta Jumping. It is still, however, a collection of orbits under the automorphism group of a quadratic form.

Fix two of the numbers, call them $W = 56, Z = 69,$ we get an indefinite binary quadratic form in $x,y$ that has infinitely many solutions. 
$$ 56 \cdot 69 = 3864 = 168 \cdot 23. $$
Here
$$ 168 = \gcd(504, WZ),  $$
From $wzxy = 504(w^2 + z^2 + x^2 + y^2)$ we have
$$ 23 \cdot 168 \cdot xy = 3 \cdot 168 (56^2 + 69^2 + x^2 + y^2), $$
$$ 23xy = 3 \left( 56^2 + 69^2 + x^2 + y^2 \right),  $$
$$ 3x^2 - 23 xy + 3y^2 = -23691.  $$
We see that solutions require $x,y>0,$ and we already have $51, 29.$

In the output below, the recipe that takes $(x,y)$ to "forward" is
$$  (x,y) \mapsto ( 12544  x  -1665  y,  1665  x  -221  y)   $$

```
3 x^2 - 23 x y + 3 y^2 = -23691


  x  29  y  51  forward  278861   37014  backward  78506   591459
  x  51  y  29  forward  591459   78506  backward  37014   278861

  x  246  y  37  forward  3024219   401413  backward  7239   54538
  x  37  y  246  forward  54538   7239  backward  401413   3024219

  x  362  y  51  forward  4456013   591459  backward  4913   37014
  x  51  y  362  forward  37014   4913  backward  591459   4456013

  x  1849  y  246  forward  22784266   3024219  backward  961   7239
  x  246  y  1849  forward  7239   961  backward  3024219   22784266

  x  7239  y  961  forward  89205951   11840554  backward  246   1849
  x  961  y  7239  forward  1849   246  backward  11840554   89205951

  x  37014  y  4913  forward  456123471   60542537  backward  51   362
  x  4913  y  37014  forward  362   51  backward  60542537   456123471

  x  54538  y  7239  forward  672071737   89205951  backward  37   246
  x  7239  y  54538  forward  246   37  backward  89205951   672071737

  x  278861  y  37014  forward  3436404074   456123471  backward  29   51
  x  37014  y  278861  forward  51   29  backward  456123471   3436404074

  x  591459  y  78506  forward  7288549206   967429409  backward  51   29
  x  78506  y  591459  forward  29   51  backward  967429409   7288549206

  x  3024219  y  401413  forward  37267450491   4946612362  backward  246   37
  x  401413  y  3024219  forward  37   246  backward  4946612362   37267450491

  x  4456013  y  591459  forward  54911447837   7288549206  backward  362   51
  x  591459  y  4456013  forward  51   362  backward  7288549206   54911447837
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Wow, amazing amount of work. I went through and collected the solutions above, and more, into orbits. There are eight $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ orbits. Since there is an obvious involution, switching $x$ and $y,$ and that linear transformation has determinant $-1,$ we could also say that there are four $GL_2 \mathbb Z$ orbits. I did check the Hurwitz type inequalities, this is very similar to what Vieta Jumping gives you. For this problem, $3 x^2 - 23 xy + 3 y^2 = - 23691,$ for any $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ orbit of solutions with both $x,y$ positive, there is a solution with $\color{red}{x + y < 4144.39}$ in that orbit.

12323^2 - 493 555^2 = 4

3 x^2 + -23 x y 3 y^2 = -23691

$$  (967429409 ,  7288549206); \; \;    ( 78506    591459); \; \;     (29,  51); \; \;   (278861,   37014); \; \;   (3436404074,   456123471);  $$

$$   (  456123471,   3436404074  ); \; \;  (  37014,    278861); \; \;  (  51,  29); \; \;     (591459,   78506); \; \;   (   7288549206,   967429409);  $$

$$  $$

$$   (  89205951,   672071737  ); \; \;  (  7239,   54538  ); \; \;  (246,  37); \; \;     (3024219,   401413); \; \;  ( 37267450491,   4946612362 );  $$

$$   (  4946612362,   37267450491   ); \; \;  (401413,   3024219); \; \;   (37,  246); \; \;     (54538,   7239); \; \;   (672071737,   89205951 );  $$

$$  $$

$$ ( 746065678538,   5620809496119  ); \; \;  (   60542537,   456123471  ); \; \;   (   4913,   37014 ); \; \;    (  362,    51); \; \;     (4456013,   591459); \; \;  (  54911447837,   7288549206   );  $$

$$ (   7288549206,   54911447837  ); \; \;   (  591459,   4456013  ); \; \;   (51,    362); \; \;     (37014,   4913); \; \;  (  456123471,   60542537   ); \; \;  (  5620809496119,   746065678538 );  $$

$$  $$

$$   ( 145911145981,   1099284926934  ); \; \;   (   11840554,   89205951  ); \; \;  ( 961,   7239   ); \; \;   (1849,  246); \; \;    (22784266,   3024219); \; \;  ( 280770508069,   37267450491  );  $$

$$  (   37267450491,   280770508069  ); \; \;  ( 3024219,   22784266  ); \; \;   (  246,  1849); \; \;     (7239,   961); \; \;  (  89205951,   11840554  ); \; \;  (  1099284926934,   145911145981 );  $$

$$  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=